# How can I add a discount and tax in Stripe checkout session in Django

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'm very new to Stripe and now I'm stuck with adding my Tax and Discount models to stripe checkout session and need some help with code.

this is my models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through='OrderItem')
    discount = models.ManyToManyField(Discount, through='OrderDiscount')
    tax = models.ManyToManyField(Tax, through='OrderTax')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created_at',)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Order {self.id} | {self.created_at.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")}'

    def get_total_cost(self):
        total = sum(item.price for item in self.items.all())

        if self.discount.exists():
            discount = sum(discount.amount for discount in self.discount.all())
            if discount <= total:
                total -= discount

        if self.tax.exists():
            tax = sum(tax.rate for tax in self.tax.all())
            tax_amount = total * tax / 100
            total += tax_amount

        return int(total)
```

As you can see, currently I calculate tax and discount directly in my model. And it's doing great.

But now I need to visualize taxes and discounts in stripe checkout form.

So this is my class for order checkout with stripe

```
class CreateCheckoutSessionOrderView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         order_id = self.kwargs["order_id"]
         DOMAIN: str = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
         order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
         # tax_rate = sum(order.tax.rate for order.tax in order.tax.all())
         # tax_name = "Taxes"
         # discount_amount = sum(order.discount.amount for order.discount in order.discount.all())
         # discount_name = 'Discounts'
         session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[
            {
                'price_data': {
                    'currency': 'usd',
                    'unit_amount': order.get_total_cost() * 100,
                    'product_data': {
                        'name': order.__str__(),
                    },
                },
                'quantity': 1,
            },
        ],
        payment_intent_data={
            'metadata': {
                'order_id': order.id,
                # 'discount_name': discount_name,
                # 'discount_amount': discount_amount,
                # 'tax_name': tax_name,
                # 'tax_rate': tax_rate
            },
        },
        mode='payment',
        success_url=DOMAIN + '/success/',
        cancel_url=DOMAIN + '/cancel/',
    )
        return JsonResponse({'id': session.id})
```

But if I uncomment the commented code I immediately get an

```
TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use tax.set() instead.
```

Any idea on how this code has to be modified to visualize my tax and discount models in stripe checkout form?

Comment: You either use Stripe's automatic tax, https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-automatic_tax or pass in tax on the line item, https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-tax_rates to surface the tax on the checkout page. As far as showing the discount, if you're trying to enable customers to pass in a promotion, you can specify this setting, https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-allow_promotion_codes. Here is a preview: https://checkout.stripe.dev/preview

Comment: @pgs Thank you! That was useful. I know about automatic tax, but here I'm talking about my own custom made taxes and discounts. But may be it's in here 
`"total_details": {
    "amount_discount": 0,
    "amount_shipping": 0,
    "amount_tax": 0
  }`

Comment: There's a problem in your commented Django code: keep in mind that when you iterate `order.tax.all()` you get `Tax` instances and not instances of the through model `OrderItem`. Same thing for`order.discount.all()`. 
Your code should work with `tax_rate = sum(tax.rate for tax in order.tax.all())` and `discount_amount = sum(discount.amount for discount in order.discount.all())`. That's the minimum change you need. You may also consider to let the DB doing the sum for you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/#joins-and-aggregates